# Including modules in Rails 3: for both instance and class methods (and with HTTPparty.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I've been wondering about the way to get both class and instance methods into a module, and then including that module into a model.

I've got it working with other examples, but I am struggling to understand where to correctly place the include HTTPparty.

Below is the details of where I am at:

```
module Vimeo

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods

   class Base      
     include HTTParty
     base_uri 'vimeo.com/api/v2'
     headers 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' 
   end

   class VimeoUser < Base

    def vimeo_account(account_name)
      @id = account_name
    end

   end

 end

   def info
     Vimeo::Base.get("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/#{@id}/info.json")
   end

end
```

with the goal of attaching it to a User model using: include Vimeo
and being able to call:

```
User.vimeo_account("name")
```

as well as

```
user = User.new
user.info
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think calling get in the following way should solve the problem.

```
def info
  Vimeo::Base.class.get("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/#{@id}/info.json")
end
```

But to me it seems like you can have a simpler setup as below: 
(unless there is more which I don't understand)

```
   class VimeoUser
     include HTTParty
     base_uri 'vimeo.com/api/v2'
     headers 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' 

   // All vimeo user related methods here, such that self.class.get etc is possible.
   end
```

Comment: The idea was to have a module that I could load into a User model - and on the User call both instance and class methods on it.

Comment: How about have a class called Vimeo (maybe in a module dedicated to all external interactions) which will have instance methods on it like user_info etc, which will give you the exact information you need in the User class abstracting User away from any http interaction. This class vimeo can include a base_uri and have instance methods doing self.class.get(<url>) and parsing json to give required info. This class Vimeo would then have the 'include HTTParty" and encapsulate all the HTTParty goriness. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I ended up doing something like that. I was overthinking the problem a bit. Thanks.